# Android get imageview width and Height using OnPreDrawListener

Tags: android

I used OnPreDrawListener to get imageview width and Hieght it return correctly but i can't use outside of that method

in OnCreate:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawingarea);
    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    ViewTreeObserver vto = img.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {     
        public boolean onPreDraw(){
            // at this point, true width and height are already determined
          int width = img.getMeasuredWidth();
          int height = img.getMeasuredHeight();
          System.out.println(width);// it return value correctly
          System.out.println(height);//it return value correctly
            img.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            return false;
        }
    });
     System.out.println(width);// it return 0
     System.out.println(height);//it return 0
    }
```

How can i get the value outsite addOnPreDrawListener Please Help

Comment: i declared width and height before on create method but also it returns 0

Comment: `System.out.println("outSide" +width);// it return 0` is executed before `addOnPreDrawListener`, check your log.

Answer (score 4):

declare your variables globally...

```
private int width;
private int height;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawingarea);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    ViewTreeObserver vto = img.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            // at this point, true width and height are already determined
            width = img.getMeasuredWidth();
            height = img.getMeasuredHeight();
            System.out.println(width);// it return value correctly
            System.out.println(height);// it return value correctly
            img.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            return false;
        }
    });
    System.out.println(width);// it return 0
    System.out.println(height);// it return 0
}
```

and you are getting correct values in `onCreate()`, I mean width and height will be zero in onCreate() as drawing of your `ImageView` is not performed yet... you can check those values in `onWindowFocusChanged()`. and your `onPreDrawListener` callback will be invoked at the the time of Drawing width and height values will be correct as ImageView has measured and layouted just before drawing...